# Shadow DOM Style Isolation

Tags: javascript, css, web-component

There seems to be an oddity in isolating Shadow DOM styles from the Main DOM styles, see the below.

In essence if I am specific about the tagName then there is isolation, but if I use * as the CSS selector then the style flows into the Shadow DOM.  The issue here is that the Main DOM is using a style library which appears to do this, I'm not sure if there are other cases of the main DOM styling overflowing into the Shadow DOM, but this clearly is and everything I've read about Shadow DOM suggests there is full isolation.

```js
class myTest extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () {
        super(); 
    }

    connectedCallback () {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
              h1.innerHTML = 'In Shadow DOM'
              shadow.appendChild(h1)
    }
   
}

customElements.define('my-test', myTest);
```

```css
h1 { color: red }
* { 
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<h1>In main DOM</h1>
<my-test></my-test>
```

Comment: _**inheritable styles**_ do style shadowDOM. See: https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/

Comment: It sort of works, I got no effect with `:host { all: initial }` as suggested by lamplightdev so tried `*:not(style) { all: initial }` and this seemed a bit better but it lost h1 font-size !  Thanks tough.

Answer (score 1):

##### Re: other answer

the `connectedCallback` *will* run multiple times when the Custom Element is **moved** in the DOM.

The `constructor` is better for creating all shadowDOM; it will execute only *once*

There hardly ever is a need for a `closed` shadowRoot, it has nothing to do with styling.
So an `open` shadowRoot is fine; returning `this.shadowRoot`, thus can be chained.

```js
customElements.define('my-test', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    const element = (tag,props) => Object.assign( document.createElement(tag) , props );
    super() // sets and returns 'this'
      .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot
      .append(
        element("H1", {
          innerHTML : 'In Shadow DOM'
        }),
        element("STYLE", {
          innerHTML : `*:not(style) { all: initial }`
        })
      );
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: red
}

* {
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<h1>In main DOM</h1>
<my-test></my-test>
```

Note: using `innerHTML` for setting `<style>` (text)content; makes for better GZIP/Brotli compression... we want small components after all.

##### Live edit `<style>` - explaining `*:not(style)`

`<style>` (and `<script>`) content are HTML, and can be displayed as HTML content.

The style is still applied, **run** below code and **edit** `red` to any HTML color you know

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<style contenteditable style="display:block">
  h1 { color: red }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Danny '365CSI' Engelman is seems it expected that the isolation is not complete, so I've looked at the link @Danny sent and edited the snipped to show what might be done if you get this problem.

```js
class myTest extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () {
        super(); 
    }

    connectedCallback () {
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' });
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
              h1.innerHTML = 'In Shadow DOM'
              shadow.appendChild(h1)
              
        // use * { all: initial } to reset. But you need to make sure <style>
        // is :not reset ( for some reason it get displayed otherwise )
        // also seems to change the h1 font size.
        
        const style = document.createElement('style')
              style.textContent = `*:not(style) { all: initial }`
              shadow.appendChild(style)
    }
   
}

customElements.define('my-test', myTest);
```

```css
h1 { color: red }
* { 
  font-family: sans-serif
}
```

```html
<h1>In main DOM</h1>
<my-test></my-test>
```